# How to run locust with multiple test files

Tags: python, performance, locust

How to run locust tests with multiple locustfiles. The locust documentation is not very clear on how to do this.

Answer (score 15):

Write tests in different files. Ensure the classes in each of these files are named differently.

import the classes from all different files into a locustfile.py ( it can have any name and need not be locustfile.py )

example.

**testfile1.py**

```
from locust import HttpUser, task, between, tag

class WebTests1(HttpUser):
    wait_time = between(0,0.1)
    def on_start(self):
        # on_start is called when a Locust start before any task is scheduled.
        pass

    def on_stop(self):
        # on_stop is called when the TaskSet is stopping
        pass


    @task(1)
    def testaURL1(self):
        response = self.client.post("/api/test/url1",
                                name="test url",
                                data="some json data",
                                headers="headers")
```

**testfile2.py**

```
from locust import HttpUser, task, between, tag

class WebTests2(HttpUser):
    wait_time = between(0,0.1)
    def on_start(self):
        # on_start is called when a Locust start before any task is scheduled.
        pass

    def on_stop(self):
        # on_stop is called when the TaskSet is stopping
        pass


    @task(1)
    def testaURL2(2self):
        response = self.client.post("/api/test/url2",
                                    name="test url",
                                    data="some json data",
                                    headers="headers")
```

**locustfile.py**

```
 from testfile1 import WebTests1
 from testfile2 import WebTests2
```

Save all the files in the same directory and run cmd `locust` or `locust -f locustfile.py`

Its recommend that you follow Python best practices for structuring your test code. Ref : https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/writing-a-locustfile.html#how-to-structure-your-test-code

Comment: How to pass the configs to WebTests1 and WebTests2?

Comment: I have 50 different classes and I want to test 10 concurrent users. But only first 10 classes are selected for test. Is there any way to test 10 user for all 50 classes?

Answer (score 2):

As per the documentation you can keep multiple locust files in a directory and pass the directory name to the argument -f/--locustfile
Locust will recursively search for files with .py extension and run all of them. It ignores any filename starts with "_" and locust.py

[Locust documentation](https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/configuration.html#using-multiple-locustfiles-at-once)

Answer (score 0):

According locust documentation in this [link](https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/configuration.html#using-multiple-locustfiles-at-once), in example you have 3 file named as locustfile1.py, locustfile2.py and locustfile3.py
in directory named `/home/user/Files`.

You can run this three files with below script:

```
locust -f /home/user/Files/locustfile1.py, /home/user/Files/locustfile2.py, /home/user/Files/locustfile3.py
```

or use this:

```
locust -f /home/user/Files
```